# Smart/Dynamic array in C

Tags: c, array, memory-management

I attempted to make a smart/dynamic array implementation in C which is supposed to be a hybrid between a C++ vector/stack/queue.

This is what i came up with:

Header (smart_array.h):

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct smart_array smart_array_t;

void smart_array_alloc(smart_array_t** array, size_t capacity);
void smart_array_free(smart_array_t** array);
int  smart_array_resize(smart_array_t* array, size_t capacity);

void smart_array_capacity(smart_array_t* array, size_t* capacity);
void smart_array_total(smart_array_t* array, size_t* total);
void smart_array_empty(smart_array_t* array, int* empty);

int  smart_array_set(smart_array_t* array, size_t index, void* item);
int  smart_array_set_back(smart_array_t* array, void* item);
int  smart_array_set_top(smart_array_t* array, void* item);

void smart_array_get(smart_array_t* array, size_t index, void** item);
void smart_array_get_back(smart_array_t* array, void** item);
void smart_array_get_top(smart_array_t* array, void** item);

int  smart_array_push_back(smart_array_t* array, void* item);
int  smart_array_push_top(smart_array_t* array, void* item);

int  smart_array_pop(smart_array_t* array, size_t index);
int  smart_array_pop_back(smart_array_t* array);
int  smart_array_pop_top(smart_array_t* array);
int  smart_array_clear(smart_array_t* array);
```

Source File: (smart_array.c):

```
#include "smart_array.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct smart_array {
    void** items;
    size_t total;
    size_t capacity;
};

void smart_array_alloc(smart_array_t** array, size_t capacity) {
    if(!(*array = malloc(sizeof(struct smart_array))))
        return;
    if(!((*array)->items = malloc(sizeof(void*) * capacity))) {
        free(*array);
        *array = 0;
        return;
    }
    (*array)->capacity = capacity;
    (*array)->total = 0;
}

void smart_array_free(smart_array_t** array) {
    if(array && *array) {
        free((*array)->items);
        free(*array);
        *array = 0;
    }
}

int smart_array_resize(smart_array_t* array, size_t capacity) {
    if(array) {
        void **items = realloc(array->items, sizeof(void*) * capacity);
        if(items) {
            array->items = items;
            array->capacity = capacity;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void smart_array_capacity(smart_array_t* array, size_t* capacity) {
    *capacity = !array ? 0 : array->capacity;
}

void smart_array_total(smart_array_t* array, size_t* total) {
    *total = !array ? 0 : array->total;
}

void smart_array_empty(smart_array_t* array, int* empty) {
    *empty = array->total == 0;
}

int smart_array_set(smart_array_t* array, size_t index, void* item) {
    if(array) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < array->total) {
            array->items[index] = item;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int smart_array_set_back(smart_array_t* array, void* item) {
    size_t total;
    smart_array_total(array, &total);
    return smart_array_set(array, total - 1, item);
}

int smart_array_set_top(smart_array_t* array, void* item) {
    return smart_array_set(array, 0, item);
}

void smart_array_get(smart_array_t* array, size_t index, void** item) {
    if(array && item) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < array->total)
            *item = array->items[index];
        else 
            *item = 0;
    }
}

void smart_array_get_back(smart_array_t* array, void** item) {
    size_t total;
    smart_array_total(array, &total);
    smart_array_get(array, total - 1, item);
}

void smart_array_get_top(smart_array_t* array, void** item) {
    smart_array_get(array, 0, item);
}

int smart_array_push_back(smart_array_t* array, void* item) {
    if(array) {
        if(array->capacity == array->total) {
            if(smart_array_resize(array, array->capacity * 2))
                return 1;
        }
        array->items[array->total++] = item;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int smart_array_push_top(smart_array_t* array, void* item) {
    if(array) {
        if(array->capacity == array->total) {
            if(smart_array_resize(array, array->capacity * 2))
                return 1;
        }
        array->total++;
        for(size_t s = array->total; s > 0; --s) 
            array->items[s] = array->items[s - 1];
        array->items[0] = item;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int smart_array_pop(smart_array_t* array, size_t index) {
    if(array && (index >= 0) && (index < array->total)) {
        array->items[index] = 0;
        for (int i = index; i < array->total - 1; ++i) {
            array->items[i] = array->items[i + 1];
            array->items[i + 1] = NULL;
        }
        array->total--;
        if ((array->total > 0) && ((array->total) == (array->capacity / 4))) {
            if(smart_array_resize(array, array->capacity / 2))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int smart_array_pop_back(smart_array_t* array) {
    size_t total;
    smart_array_total(array, &total);
    return smart_array_pop(array, total - 1);
}

int smart_array_pop_top(smart_array_t* array) {
    return smart_array_pop(array, 0);
}

int smart_array_clear(smart_array_t* array) {
    int empty;
    smart_array_empty(array, &empty);
    while(!empty) {
        smart_array_pop_top(array);
        smart_array_empty(array, &empty);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test (main.c):

````
#include "smart_array.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_smart_array(smart_array_t* array) {
    size_t total, capacity;
    
    smart_array_total(array, &total);
    smart_array_capacity(array, &capacity);
    
    printf("Array total: %i\n", total);
    printf("Array capacity: %i\n", capacity);
    
    printf("Array items:\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        int* val;
        smart_array_get(array, i, (void**)&val);
        printf("\t%i\n", *val);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    smart_array_t* a;
    smart_array_alloc(&a, 4);
    
    int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* z = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* w = malloc(sizeof(int));
    
    *x = 3;
    *y = 56;
    *z = 100;
    *w = 87;
    
    smart_array_push_back(a, x);
    smart_array_push_back(a, x);
    smart_array_push_top(a, w);
    smart_array_push_back(a, w);
    smart_array_push_top(a, y);
    
    print_smart_array(a);
    
    smart_array_clear(a);
    
    print_smart_array(a);
    
    free(x);
    free(y);
    free(z);
    free(w);
    smart_array_free(&a);
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### File Structure

The code is well organised into testing, implementation, and headers. Including `stddef.h` is appropriate in your header since you use `size_t`.

### Consistency

Consider making sure the pointers are valid, for example, with `assert`, or at least in documentation, before writing to them. The users of this code might not understand, and it's not ideal for them to go sifting through your code to find the problem. At least, have it consistent; in `smart_array_set` it checks for null when the others do not.

`typedef struct smart_array smart_array_t` is potentially problematic. See discussion [type followed by _t represent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231760/2472827) and [Linux Kernel Style Guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs). I think that one's users should be free to express it as a `typedef`, so I would just stick with `struct smart_array`; C and C++ are different languages.

### Return Values

Returning `void` from `smart_array_alloc` is problematic because there are two different paths it could take; one would have to query the pointer to see if it succeeded. It should be easy to use properly, and as it stands, using this without checking is an (undocumented) mistake.

I would expect `smart_array_get(_*)` to return the item. As it stands, one has a pointer to the item passed in and it returns `void`. This can be annoying when functional composition is desired. Same thing with most of one's other functions. At least shortly document them explaining the change from C++.

I expect some sort of error or feedback when accessing out-of-bounds, but this does nothing. It is arguably not the best choice.

### Constructor Simplification

I would expect `smart_array_alloc` is going to be called with the default constructor most of the time, so I would consider make one not including `capacity` that calls the one that does.

The two allocations are properly handled by `smart_array_alloc`, but they could be simplified by calling `smart_array_free` instead. One doesn't need two allocations, since it's aligned already, it would be simpler to allocate it as one.

```
if(!(*array = malloc(sizeof struct smart_array + sizeof(void*) * capacity)
    return (fail);
(*array)->items = (void *)(*array + 1);
```

In fact, there are multiple memory allocations that could be all calling `smart_array_resize`.

> If ptr is a null pointer, realloc() shall be equivalent to malloc() for the specified size.

I would consider exposing the `struct smart_pointer` in the header for allocation on the stack and simplifying this even more, but that's a design decision that is not always appropriate.

### Zero Values

`smart_array_set_back` and `smart_array_set_top` will have undefined behaviour when empty or capacity is zero.

### Use of Private Members

I think it's okay to use `total` as a data member in this private code instead of getting it through the public outward-facing `smart_array_total`. `smart_array_clear`, with access to private members, should be very simple.